# How to move my Python application to the web?

Tags: python, saas

This month, I learnt Python. I compiled the code and am able to run it on my laptop.  A simple code that asks the user yes/no responses to questions that helps them traverse through a flowchart and end up with a final choice/result.

How do I turn this into a Python Web Application that can be accessed by others over a URL and not be dependent on my laptop to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the parts of your app that have its logic from the ones which react to and update window content.

Then you need to rewrite the window management part for the web. From the scratch. Also other parts if they rely on things that are not available in a browser (usually local filesystem access).

It is doable, but not that trivial as web apps have different architecture from desktop apps, there are issues with concurrency, preserving app state, and browser limitations, to name few.

Anything more detailed requires you to describe what it is that your app does and how.

Comment: I wish the question wasnt closed and allowing others to answer.   But anyway, I am a kid learning to code.  I learnt Python and am asking simple yes/no answers to the user and based on their answers, after a series of steps on the flowchart, output a result/choice to them.   I am trying to make this a webapp.

Comment: @ums2026 better start making webapp from scratch and just use your existing code where you can. webapps are a completely different kind of code from desktop apps. even more so, if your app is just console instead of windows based.

Comment: Hi @Gnudiff! I won't start a new thread since this one is already here. I have some apps which do some data operations based on .csv and .xlsx files (preprocessing, standarizing, merging, etc.). I want to push that online, since there are more and more programs, I want end users to run those programs by themselves. So far I'm able to export the .py as .exe standalone and send it to them, but I'd love to make a web app to avoid having to share the source code. The program uses pandas and numpy mainly. Would that be a complicated operation?

Comment: @currentlyunknown hey there. you are mistaken. this is not a thread. the idea of site is not programming *discussion*, but rather questions and answers. if you have another question you'd better write it as one. I can see that you haven't tried implementing any web service so the best idea would be to try and do it. there is a whole can of things to do there.